# best or recommended way to setup CD for a non-dockerized django website?

Tags: django, jenkins, cd

I am trying to figure out the best way to deploy code that is merged to master of one branch.

My jenkins server and my website server are 2 different servers and my best guess for how to do CD is to just use the `scp` command for copying over the files but was wondering if there is a method that is more sophisticated.

I am looking for a method that does not dockerize my django application at this time and most of the search results online keep giving examples of how to do it with a dockerized django application.

Comment: You can also use git to push/pull to/from the server.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the server you deploy. I believe scp is a simple and good option.

The leading sophisticated method to deploy on other servers is terraform.
look at how many providers it can deploy to: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/index.html

Another solution I know is ansible, it's generally used to create a VM and set it up with your project. I would say terraform matches more your use case.

And obviously as you said there is docker. The sophisticated way with docker would be to push to a private registry and have a software watching it that would deploy the new image when available